# Mathquill Having No Effect

Tags: javascript, html, mathquill

I am attempting to do some simple static formatting with Mathquill. When I test my code, the text isn't formatted, nor are there any errors to let me know if I did anything wrong.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/mathquill/mathquill.css"/>
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/mathquill/mathquill.js"></script>
        <script>
            var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
            var problemSpan = document.getElementById('problem');
            MQ.StaticMath(problemSpan);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Solve <span id="problem">ax^2 + bx + c = 0</span>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

All paths are correct, as there are no 404 errors.

[image: Page Output]

Comment: are you getting any errors?  the DOM might not be ready before you call problemSpan =

Answer (score 1):

style tag is not needed, and interferes with link tag.  Need to wait for DOM ready.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
      var problemSpan = document.getElementById('problem');
      MQ.StaticMath(problemSpan);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Solve <span id="problem">ax^2 + bx + c = 0</span>.</p>
</body>

</html>
```